# Android BitmapFactory.decodeFile skia error

Tags: java, android, imageview, bitmapfactory

I'm designing an activity that shows some images. The code below gets image files and places them into the screen.

```
        for(int i=0;i<photoPaths.size();i++){
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            //Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(photoPaths.get(i)).getAbsolutePath());
            Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(photoPaths.get(i)).getAbsolutePath());
            int imageH=bm.getHeight();
            int imageW=bm.getWidth();
            ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageBitmap(bm);
            int padding=10;
            image.setPadding(0, padding, padding, 0);
         }
```

The code is running well while placing 5 photos. After them when 6th is placing code fails.

Here is the LogCat messages:

```
       06-27 11:13:13.202: D/skia(17373): --- decoder->decode returned false
       06-27 11:13:13.202: D/AndroidRuntime(17373): Shutting down VM
       06-27 11:13:13.202: W/dalvikvm(17373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4142c2a0)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:652)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:451)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at .PhotoGallery.onCreate(PhotoGallery.java:94)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
       06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed to pass the `options` object to decodeFile:

```
 Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(photoPaths.get(i)).getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   06-27 11:13:13.202: E/AndroidRuntime(17373): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

You ran out of memory.  YOu need to reduce the memory usage of your application.  Note that if the image is fairly large (say 30+MB) it alone may be too much for memory.